# init (sub)class later and attach it to instantiated parent

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to get my design straight and am wondering if there is a way to "attach" a child-class to an already instantiated parent-class.

Example:

```
CLASS webshopOrder { ... }
CLASS deliveryAddress EXTENDS webshopOrder {
    public function __construct($parentOrder) {
        // pseudo: parent = $parentOrder;
    }
}

$order = new webshopOrder;
$deliveryAddress = new deliveryAddress($order);
```

Now, when I need the delivery address later in my code I don't want the order to initiate (expensively) again and would like to use the existing instance.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does the `deliveryAddress` extend `webshopOrder` to begin with? When you extend a class, the child class inherits all the methods and properties from the parent. A `webshopOrder` will most likely contain a bunch of methods and properties that an address wouldn't need. It would make more sense of you had some method in your `webshopOrder`-class that was: `addDeliveryAddress($deliveryAddress)` where you pass an instance of the `deliveryAddress`-class.

Comment: Totally agree with Magnus. What you need is composition, not inheritance.

Comment: Have I understood EXTENDing wrong? Now that you mention it, delAddr is not a subset of order, you're right - it's more of a property. With this thought in mind I will evaluate again ;) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can inject address class in your order class by constructor, and there is little mistake in your design, logically shop order should contain the delivery address, not address have order. so I make some update:

```
class DeliveryAddress{..}

class WebShopOrder { 
  public $deliveryAddress;

    public function __construct(DeliveryAddress $deliveryAddress) {
    $this->deliveryAddress = $deliveryAddress;
  }
}

$delivery_address = new DeliveryAddress;
$order = new WebShopOrder($delivery_address);
```

Comment: In my opinion the address doesn't need to known the order. The relation should be inverse.

Comment: yeah you are right, shop contain the order address. I am wondering why he design in such way..

Comment: It's a bit weird to pass the address into the order in the constructor for two reasons. 1. You would need to do that for all properties (addresses, products etc) or it would be inconsistent. 2. It also means that the address needs to be created before the order. In my opinion, you would first create an order, which you then fill with the necessary information using setters.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you,yeah, in either cases we should have address first, to proceed the order. I really don't know in which scenario the question is represented. if it is initial stage then what you are saying is correct. but it is a last stage then I hope my suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: thanks guys, in my case all orders have already been placed so the address is a property of the order: I think I will go with lazy initialization.